# EF Core Query Many to Many with filtering

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following table structure:

[image]

I want to retrieve all funds for provided **reportId**.
I did it this way:

```
                var result = _context.FundsInReports
                        .Join(_context.Funds,
                                a=> a.FundId,
                                b => b.Id,
                                (fir, fund) => new {fir, fund})
                        .Join(_context.Reports,
                                a=> a.fir.ReportId,
                                b=> b.Id,
                                (fir2, report) => new { fir2, report})
                        .Where(q=> q.fir2.fir.ReportId==reportId)
                        .Select(res => new FundsResponse()
                        {
                            FundId = res.fir2.fund.Id,
                            LegalName = res.fir2.fund.LegalName,
                            HeaderName = res.fir2.fund.HeaderName,
                            PortfolioCurrency = res.fir2.fund.PortfolioCurrencyId,
                            BaseCurrency = res.fir2.fund.BaseCurrencyId,
                            FileName = res.fir2.fund.FileName,
                            Locked = res.fir2.fund.Locked

                        }).ToList();
```

and this works fine...
However, I would like to use this code:

```
                var result = _context.Funds
                    .Include(a => a.FundsInReports)
                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Report)         // Many to many , intellisense is not working here !
                    .Select(res => new FundsResponse()
                    {
                        FundId = res.Id,
                        LegalName = res.LegalName,
                        HeaderName = res.HeaderName,
                        PortfolioCurrency = res.PortfolioCurrencyId,
                        BaseCurrency = res.BaseCurrencyId,
                        FileName = res.FileName,
                        Locked = res.Locked

                    }).ToList();
```

but I don't know how to add filtering (where) into this code.
Thanks...

Comment: You will need to add joins like your first section of code or you need to specify the relationships in the entity models (and mappings). The latter is easier to do and to reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use Include with custom projections.  They are alternative approaches to generating results.  So just run

```
var result = _context.FundsInReport
    .Where( fr => fr.ReportId == someId )
    .Select(fr => new FundsResponse()
    {
        FundId = fr.Fund.Id,
        LegalName = fr.Fund.LegalName,
        HeaderName = fr.Fund.HeaderName,
        PortfolioCurrency = fr.Fund.PortfolioCurrencyId,
        BaseCurrency = fr.Fund.BaseCurrencyId,
        FileName = fr.Fund.FileName,
        Locked = fr.Fund.Locked
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you David... It is obvious when I look at it now :)  
It works like a charm. Perfect!